# TF unable to determine workspace

Tags: jenkins, tfs, msbuild

I get this error:

```
 Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'.
```

I have checkout the workspace from Jenkins plugin (TFS-plugin). Then I run a MSBuild script where I want to checkout a file with this target:

```
 <!-- Checkout before building -->
 <Target Name="CheckoutUpdateVersion">
    <Message Text="***** Checkout $(UpdateVersionFile) *****" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="E:\WS\Jenkins\workspace\TD_-_Build_TFS\" Command="$(tf)  checkout E:\WS\Jenkins\workspace\TD_-_Build_TFS\src\rubin\Scripts\update_version.sql" />       
</Target>
```

I have checked so my workspace I mapped and it is mapped to the WorkingDirectory that is above.

Answer (score 0):

Workspaces are tied to a machine **and** user. I suppose that the Jenkins agent is running with another user account which has no proper workspace definition.

Some tips:

- you cannot use the same local directory in different workspaces
- to define a workspace for build user account, logon using the latter or run-as Team Explorer (or run-as a Command Prompt and use TF to define the workspace)

Comment: Ok. That is true. It is running as Another user. Is it possible to use /login to solve that or they need to run with the same user?

Comment: It should work, but it implies displaying the password in cleartext. I edit the answer with some additional ideas.

Comment: I have now Jenkins running as the same user as I checkout. But still the same error. :-(

Comment: Can you run the Jenkins Agent interactively? If that works, the problem is the lack of the user profile while running as a service.